# Android view binding onClick event fails

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having this view binding in a kotlin android app:

fragmentCurrentCounting Class:

```
    private lateinit var _binding: FragmentcurrentcountingBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding?hl=en
        _binding = FragmentcurrentcountingBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)// inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentcurrentcounting, container, false)
        val view = _binding.root
        _binding.DepartureTime.setOnClickListener{TimeDialog(view)}
        return view
    }

    fun TimeDialog(view:View)
    {
        TimePickerDialog(requireContext(), getTimePickerListener(),12,12,true ).show()
    }

    private fun getTimePickerListener() =
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _, hourOfDay, minute ->
            //this.view.textView.text = "%02d:%02d".format(hourOfDay, minute)
            var editText = this.view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.DepartureTime)
            editText?.setText("%02d:%02d".format(hourOfDay, minute));
        }
```

The TimePickerDialog is not showing, instead the app is crashing. Why??

Thats how the xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragmentCurrentCounting">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="5pt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/MyTime" />

      .....

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="AddButtonClick"
            android:text="@string/Add" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

somehow the override fun onCreateView() never gets called? Somebody has an explanation for that?

Comment: Observation: you didn't call `TimePickerDialog().show()` so it won't show.  Please also add relevant codes for your `getTimePickerListener()` method, seems it's the one causing the crash.

Comment: i added the getTimePickerListener() and also added .show() in the code. But i tried to set a breakpoint in OnCreateView and somehow it never gets called...

Comment: `getTimePickerListener()` looks fine.  Other stuff might cause the crash. It will better if you also share the crash log.

Comment: currently the app is not crashing anymore, it was because i manually added an onClick Event in the xml file that could not be found (thats another question i did not understand, because the function was there. Also tried to put it into several places, if it bubbles up.)

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you want to acheive.
For sure you want to show 'TimeDialog' when you tap the button.

onclick listener yields a view which was clicked:

`_binding.DepartureTime.setOnClickListener{ buttonView -> TimeDialog(buttonView)}`

but in your case you're passing parent view, and at the time of delcaring listener (onCreateView) it could not be yet attached to window, so you faced crash.

on the other hand, not sure how implementation of TimePicker looks like - maybe it requires dialog to be shown, like

`TimePickerDialog(..).show()`